# AnyLogic agent population for a machine group

Tags: anylogic, agent

For scalabilty, I wanted to use an agent population that represents multiple machines. In my model, I already have an agent Product that contains all information such as the machine ID and the processing time. After an availabilty check, the Product agent should be send to the right machine to be produced.

Currently, I do not understand how to represent the multiple machines inside the agent population. For example, my Product agent should go to machine 1, so the machine ID in the Product agent is has integer 1. How can I send the Product to the right machine inside the machine population?

I tried to put the logic inside the agent machine. So, enter block -> queue block -> delay block --> exit block. I get stuck on how to send to Product to the right machine.

Comment: Check my full workshop and base model on this topic: https://youtu.be/OWwjKqKUA1A?si=B34P6YFe0Ueu3vKl

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the video. It was very insightful and I think I can use it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

, you have described very little information to answer.  the question is which Anylogic library you use to solve the problem?
I think that this is a process modeling library.
In this library, you can refer to your agent, for example, in Selectoutput via agent.* where * is the name of your property and divide the application agents as you need.
I also advise you to look at a ready-made example, which is analyzed in the help of Anylogic for servicing employees in the bank. there is a similar functionality implemented in terms of determining where the customer wants to go to the cashier or ATM